# In Java, how do I set each character as an integer?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to put the entire alphabet from A-Z into an array of 0 to 25. From then I would like to manipulate it. So, for example if the user input a character and a number, I would be able to move that character by a certain amount on the alphabet.

For example the letter "A" and the number "3" will give me the letter "D" in the end.

How should I implement this? Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `String alphabets = "AB...YZ"` and use `String::charAt` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for an array. In Java, a `char` is an [integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1). So you could use something like

```
int count = 3;
char out = (char) ('A' + (count % ('Z' - 'A')));
System.out.println(out);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
D
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it by just a couple of seconds :(

Comment: What if I need it to wrap around? Right now if my characters are near the end of the alphabet, it doesn't go back to "abc".

Comment: @quidproquo In fact, it does. That's why I took the modulus of 'Z' - 'A' with `count % ('Z' - 'A')`

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant if the starting letter was not 'A' but rather some other alphabet (ex. 'Y'). Because if I understand it correctly the modulus will prevent my "count" from going above 25?

Comment: Correct. Because that's what you asked for.  If you want something else you'll need to explain what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay, I will think about this more before asking, thank you for giving me a good point to start from!

Answer (score 1):

You can write directly `'A' + n`:

```
char getChar(int n) { 
   return 'A' + n; 
}
```

If the input is not necessarily correct you can add your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ASCII value of the letters. 
A=65
B=66....

Take the char you need to know the value and do ('A' - 'A' + 1) +3 
Replace the first A by any letter you need the value of